# Embedding the plane into 3d space for a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pair of 3d vectors u and v. I have another function f mapping 3d space onto real numbers (so, a scalar field). I want to draw a 2d plot f(x*u + y*v) using a colormap. So I need to end up with a matrix *z* filled with values of *f*, so I can go

```
pyplot.imshow(z)
```

But how can I do this? I tried

```
x = numpy.linspace(0, s2, 500)
y = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 500)
xs, ys = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)
z = f(u*xs + v*ys) # Not actually valid
```

Hoping that `u*xs + v*ys` would produce a matrix of 3d vectors, but that doesn't work. Also, even if I can get a matrix A of 3d vectors, what's the best way to get the matrix obtained by applying f to each element?

Comment: Without knowing `f`, how is anyone supposed to understand what's happening here?! Also, the inputs `u`, `v` must be known. If you don't want to limit your chances of getting help here, consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest f is any function mapping 3d vectors onto scalars. The point is I need a method that will work no matter what f is. u and v are certainly known.

Comment: Also, to be clear, this isn't a "I'm doing X, but it's not working!" question, this is a "I want behavior Y, how can I get that?" question.

Comment: *"I want behavior Y, how can I get that?"*  [necessarily preceeds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMWeL.png) *"I'm doing X, but it's not working!"*. The latter is the advanced version of the former. You're stuck at step one here. Since e.g. `lambda x,y,z: 0.0` is a function that meets the criteria from the question, it's pretty obvious that you haven't provided enough information to answer the question. Since it's also not clear what `xu + yv` would result in, you would want to make more specific statements on `u` and `v`.

Comment: I don't understand. If I asked "how can I add two numbers together in python?" you wouldn't say "it depends on the numbers, if it's 5 and 2 then type 5 + 2". I need a *general* method for taking a function f (in the sense of a mathematical function - I don't mind how it's actually implemented in the code) and doing with it what's described in the question. When I write xu + yv, I'm taking x and y to be real numbers.

Comment: If u and v are two fixed vectors (in my case they will be (-1, 1, 0) and (-0.5, -0.5, 1), but that's really not important), and f maps 3d space onto real numbers, then (x, y) -> f(xu+yv) defines a mapping from the plane onto real numbers. I want to plot that function using a colormap (ie, so the plot looks sort of [like this](https://mvngu.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/complex-sine.png)), and I want to be able to do this for any function f. In fact, I want to write a python function plotFunc(f) to do this, so you should treat f as unknown, but mapping triplets of floats onto floats.

Comment: If you were asking *"how to add a string and a float in python"*, you wouldn't get any answer. If you added an example, saying *`a = "5"; b=2`, how to calculate `a+b`*, the solution `float(a)+b` would be pretty obvious. I suppose something similar happening here. The information in the last comment seems relevant although not sufficient for me to make sense of it; you should anyways add it to the question instead of the comments.